# Trying to match my HTML/CSS to my Figma layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, figma

I'm fairly new to CSS/HTML however I'm trying to take my Figma Design and write the code for it. I'd need the website to be responsive to different screen-sizes. I have the image to what I believe is the right place, however I can't seem to get my text into the right places, and I don't know how to change button size or color.

I've included my Figma Design and my code.

https://www.figma.com/file/QYUmBdCX7PJYi5V8XV63e3/Shield-Split-Designs?node-id=9%3A55&t=DaKGZA7LVNNQBZbE-1

HTML:

```
<docType html!>
<html>
<head>
<title>Arriving soon...</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href="Stylesheets/style.css">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<img src="Transparent%20Logo.png">  
</div>
<div id="logo-text">
<p1>Split Shield</p1>
</div>
<div id="slogan">
<p>The next generation of internet security is arriving soon...</p>    
</div>
<div id="content-button">
<button>Check out our concept</button>  
</div>   
    
</body>
    
</html>



</docType>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #2F2F41;
}

#logo:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

#logo img {
    max-width: 31.2%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 8.6%;
}

#logo-text p1 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700px;
    font-size: 64px;
    display: flex;
}

#slogan p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400px;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#button {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center; 
}

#button button {
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    
}
```

Comment: display: flex; might be handy: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and study html5 for a bit longer: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/main/src/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways you can acheive your target, one of them is using grid, so in this case i'll show you how to go with grid-template, and how to make you're code equal to the figma design.

but you need to read more about the HTML5, and CSS so you can handle more in future,

at least i'll focus on some mistakes you have done,
first, HTML5 declaration is used in this way <!doctype HTML>, the exclamation mark at the first, and there's no closure tag for it, so you just declare the doc type at the first.
second, you need to target your parents / childs correctly at your css code.

anyway, here is an example to go through

```css
body {
  background-color: #2F2F41;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "a b" auto "a c" auto "a d" auto;
}

#logo {
  grid-area: a;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo-text {
  grid-area: b;
}

#slogan {
  grid-area: c;
}

#content-button {
  grid-area: d;
}

#logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo-text p1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700px;
  font-size: 64px;
  display: flex;
}

#slogan p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#button {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

#button {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  width:80%;
  display:flex;
  border-radius:15px;
  height:3rem;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/j5hXXVP/imgbin-macos-virtual-private-network-computer-icons-apple-png.png" alt="imgbin-macos-virtual-private-network-computer-icons-apple-png" border="0">
    </div>
    <div id="logo-text">
      <p1>Split Shield</p1>
    </div>
    <div id="slogan">
      <p>The next generation of internet security is arriving soon...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content-button">
      <div id="button">Check out our concept</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked pretty well - however the vertical spacing between elements is huge. What would be the strategy for diminishing this.

Not to mention the image doesn't seem to be centered at all